# Laravel Artisan command - "Class not found"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, octobercms

Ok, i've got some voodoo magic here. inb4 - I've made composer dump and dump-autoload 100 000 times.

```
<?
namespace Cds\Goods\Classes;

use Cds\Goods\Classes\Logs;
use Cds\Goods\Classes\AttributeUniteFront;

class ShiptorSync extends Shiptor{

    public static function sync_products() {    
        Logs::add_to_log("shiptor_sync", date("d.m.Y"), "begin sync shiptor products");
        $name = AttributeUniteFront::getSlugProduct($item->cds_products_id);
    }
}
```

Here is my class which function sync_products() I'm calling in console command, like that

```
<?php
​
namespace App\Console\Commands;
​
use Cds\Goods\Classes\ShiptorSync;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
​
/**
 * Class ShiptorSynchronizeProducts
 */
class ShiptorSynchronizeProducts extends Command
{
  /**
   * The name and signature of the console command.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $signature = 'shiptor:products:synchronize';
​
  /**
   * The console command description.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $description = 'Sync goods';
​
  /**
   * Execute the console command.
   */
  public function handle()
  {
    ShiptorSync::sync_products();
  }
}
```

And everytime when i run it from console -   Class 'Cds\Goods\Classes\AttributeUniteFront' not found

But! Class Logs found succesfully. What the heck...

[image]

Class is at his place

AttributeFront got right namespace
[image]

And even in IDE it paints with a grey font and error like it is unused on page. What can it be????

[image]

[image]

**No, really what the hell is this? It told that class not found and throws me full listing of not-founded class in error!!!**

[image]

Comment: first line of question - did it 100 000 times

Comment: Cds\Goods\Classes\AttributeUniteFront is this class place in vendor?

Comment: It is in OctoberCMS plugin in folder /var/www/site.test/web/plugins/cds/goods/classes

Comment: near class Logs loads perfectly

Comment: can you post composer.json where this namespace registered?

Comment: where do i need it? i made simple composer.json at plugin folder and it not helps

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nhjHt5C8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174809/discussion-between-evgeny-malkov-and-j-doe).

Answer (score 1):

Add to command controller:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

In Kernel.php:

```
protected $commands = [
        //
        '\App\Console\Commands\ShiptorSynchronizeProducts',
    ];
```

Then, why not just handle() the sync_products in the command? Also, $item does not appear to be defined.

Add this to the command file:

```
    use Cds\Goods\Classes\Logs;
    use Cds\Goods\Classes\AttributeUniteFront;

public function handle()
  {
    Logs::add_to_log("shiptor_sync", date("d.m.Y"), "begin sync shiptor products");
        $name = AttributeUniteFront::getSlugProduct($item->cds_products_id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gosh, i dunno why but the case was in opening short PHP tag, although short_open_tag is enabled. However i change it and everything works.

Comment: Can you please explain your solution a little more?